# how to convert universal time to AM and PM?

Tags: c#

I converted 2014-08-21 12:00 AM to 2014-08-21T18:30:00.000Z using

```
ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK")
```

But now i want to reverse it.
How can i convert 2014-08-21T18:30:00.000Z to 2014-08-21 12:00 AM?

Comment: The converse of `ToUniversalTime` is `ToLocalTime`.

Comment: [ToLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx). If you want AM/PM, you get it with [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) and the right format string. Note, that a `DateTime` value in and of itself does *not* contain any AM/PM or other shenanigans. It is basically a fancy `Int64` value counting ticks since `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Its giving me a error how can i change it universal time to local time : @foreach (var item in Model) { <tr class="rowclass"> <td class="tdEndTime"> <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>Convert.ToDateTime(item.EndTime).ToLocalTime()) </b> </td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var localFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm tt";
string universalFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK";

var now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString(localFormat));

var universal = now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(universalFormat);
Console.WriteLine(universal);

var newNow = Convert.ToDateTime(universal).ToLocalTime().ToString(localFormat); 
Console.WriteLine(newNow);
```

Output:

```
8/24/2014 11:16 PM
2014-08-25T06:16:45.229Z
8/24/2014 11:16 PM
```

Last one is a `string`, just like the universal one, but you may forgo the `ToString()` conversion and simply format it on demand.  Up to you, I simply provide the foundation code.

**EDIT:**

Per OP's request in the comments:

```
// Here's one way of converting a string to DateTime.
var date = Convert.ToDateTime("8/24/2014 11:16:45 PM");

// Here's one way of creating DateTime by providing arguments.
var date = new DateTime(2014, 8, 24, 23, 16, 45);
```

I'd also recommend providing localization as one of the arguments, just to be safe.  Once you have those variables, you may do all the same actions as the prior code showcased.

If you want just the date or just the time, simply format your output accordingly:

```
// If you want strings.
date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
date.ToSTring("HH:mm:ss");

// If you want DateTime and TimeSpan
date.Date();
date.TimeOfDay();
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i pick date only from 8/24/2014 11:16:45 PM.   Like date= 8/24/2014    and time=11:16:45 PM

Comment: OP has the universal as a `string`, but I would urge everyone to keep a `DateTime` a `DateTime` for as long as possible and only `ToString` it at the last moment before the output. `var universal = now.ToUniversalTime(); Console.WriteLine(universal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK"));`

Comment: @Corak Right, that's why I made that little comment at the end of my answer.  That is, of course, unless he knows for sure that he won't use that `struct` anywhere else... because it may be costly keeping it around for too long.

Comment: @ManjitSingh - for date "only": `now.Date;`. But remember, there will still be a "time", but it will be `00:00:00`. As I said, `DateTime` is basically an `Int64` number. It has no real "date" part or "time" part.

Comment: @Corak What in the world are you talking about?  `DateTime` is not `Int64`.  `DateTime` is a struct.

Comment: @B.K. - yes, it's a struct, but it's still basically an `Int64` counting ticks since `DateTime.MinValue` with two "magic" bits to store if it is local or UTC. See [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.DateTime.aspx) under "Remarks". - The example there `0100-01-01 00:00:00` would be the `Int64` value `31241376000000000`.

Comment: @Corak But how is this relevant to anything he's asking?

Comment: It is relevant in understanding, that OP won't get a `DateTime` object with "date only" or "time only". He may get a `DateTime` object where the time is `00:00:00` or a `DateTime` object where the date is `0001-01-01`. But those objects still represent date *and* time parts.

Comment: Thanku very much @B.K.

Comment: Its giving me a error how can i change it universal time to local time :                      @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <tr class="rowclass">
      <td class="tdEndTime"> 
         <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>Convert.ToDateTime(item.EndTime).ToLocalTime()) </b>
  </td>

Comment: @ManjitSingh Please post a new question, explaining the exact error details.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this in LINQPad:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2014-08-21 12:00 AM")
   .ToUniversalTime()
   .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK");

var dtReverse = DateTime.Parse("2014-08-20T18:30:00.000Z")
   .ToLocalTime()
   .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt");
```

My results:

```
2014-08-20T18:30:00.000Z
2014-08-21 12:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply try this:

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(date);
```

Also check [DateTimeOffSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx)

> Represents a point in time, typically expressed as a date and time of
>   day, relative to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Also

```
DateTime changedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(dateStr),
    DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime dt = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
```